# Installing R packages remotely with no special privileges. A.k.a. corruptions from installing R packages in /tmp/

Tags: r, path, installation, package, distributed-computing

I'm distributing jobs over a cluster and I'd rather not go to each machine and manually install the right packages.  The job controller runs scripts as nobody, so I have to specify uncontroversial writeable paths for the installations.  I actually had this working solution:

```
`%ni%` = Negate(`%in%`) ### "not in"
.libPaths("/tmp/") ### for local (remote non super user) install of packages
if ("xxx" %ni% installed.packages()) {install.packages("xxx", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", lib="/tmp/")}
# ... and more
library(xxx)
# ... and more
```

It worked at first, but a week later I've got a strange problem.

```
> library(xxx)
Error in library(xxx) : there is no package called 'xxx'
```

xxx (and other packages) is in the manifest of installed.packages(), .libPaths is reporting /tmp/ on the path, and ls shows a folder for the package in /tmp/.  Reinstalling with install.packages throws an error, as does remove.package, update.package, and find.package.

Two questions:
Is there a different way that I ought to have managed the remote install?
Any ideas what has caused my problem with the failure to load the package?

Please save me from having to implement a kludge like

```
locdir <- paste("/tmp/", as.integer(runif(1, 1, 100000)), sep='')
system(paste("mkdir", locdir))
.libPaths(locdir)
install.packages("xxx", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", lib=locdir)
library(xxx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need option `character.only = TRUE`, although it is weird that your code worked before but not anymore. Anyway, try this function:

```
packageLoad<-function(libName){
    # try to load the package
    if (!require(libName,character.only = TRUE)){ 
      # if package is not available, install it
      install.packages(libName,dep=TRUE, 
         repos="http://cran.r-project.org",lib="/tmp/",destdir="/tmp/")
      # try again
      if(!require(libName,character.only = TRUE)) 
         stop(paste("Package ",libName," 
            not found and its installation failed."))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code worked before because it installed the package in the same session that it used it, and it stops working because R thinks the meanwhile-broken package is currently properly installed.  It'll take me a few days to get in and test your code, but thanks so much for responding.  This is not such a popular question.

Comment: It's been over two years, but I just accepted this, editing the original answer by putting /tmp/ in quotes, and setting both lib and destdir equal to it.